How to escape symbols in jq query?
I try to get area of JSON created by kubectl as another user.
runuser -l username -c "kubectl get ing -A -o json | jq --arg namespace "default" -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.namespace==$namespace))'"
and get
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.items | map(select(.metadata.namespace==))
jq: 1 compile error


The issue is that the jq expression is only double-quoted, as it is part of the double-quoted string which is the argument to the runuser command.
Therefore, the jq internal variable $namespace will be mistaken by the shell as a shell variable, and it will expand to nothing as it is not set to anything in the shell. This introduces a syntax error in the jq expression.
To solve this with as few keystrokes as possible, escape the $ in $namespaces as \$.  This will "hide it" from the shell:
runuser -l username -c "
    kubectl get ing -A -o json | 
    jq -r --arg namespace default '.items | map(select(.metadata.namespace == \$namespace))'"

Alternatively, use runuser to get the JSON that you want to parse and parse it afterwards (this is what I would do, there is no point running jq as that other user):
runuser -l username -c 'kubectl get ing -A -o json' |
jq -r --arg namespace default '.items | map(select(.metadata.namespace == $namespace))'

